# How to determine which control causes the ViewState loading to fail?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I am facing a Viewstate load issue with my page.

Page has a login facility to log in admin and non-admin users. A strange behavior occurs when a non-admin user logs in to the page and clicks a checkbox which has autopostback enabled. (error details are given below)

Later I found that, in the navigation panel on the left side (which hosts links)

Sidebar is something as depicted below

```
Security
---------
Link1
Link2
Link3

Configuration
---------
Link1
Link2
```

If anything more than appears under the "Configuration" section, this exception gets thrown. The links are dynamically removed (from a full list) based on the user's privilege on Page_Load.

How can I trace this kind of issues? I enabled all the exceptions in Visual Studio but it's not breaking to see which control causes this issue?

> Failed to load viewstate.  The control tree into which viewstate is
>   being loaded must match the control tree that was used to save
>   viewstate during the previous request.  For example, when adding
>   controls dynamically, the controls added during a post-back must match
>   the type and position of the controls added during the initial
>   request.

```
[HttpException (0x80004005): Failed to load viewstate.  The control tree into which viewstate is being loaded must match the control tree that was used to save viewstate during the previous request.  For example, when adding controls dynamically, the controls added during a post-back must match the type and position of the controls added during the initial request.]
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadViewStateRecursive(Object savedState) +380
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadChildViewStateByIndex(ArrayList childState) +144
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadViewStateRecursive(Object savedState) +214
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadChildViewStateByIndex(ArrayList childState) +144
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadViewStateRecursive(Object savedState) +214
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadChildViewStateByIndex(ArrayList childState) +144
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadViewStateRecursive(Object savedState) +214
   System.Web.UI.Page.LoadAllState() +464
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1729
```

Comment: Instead of removing, can you try to only set `Visible = false` on the controls? That way the viewstate information is intact, but the controls won't be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the page cycle in this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms972976.aspx) you can see that the viewstate is loaded before page load and saved before render. You are removing the controls in page load which is after the load of viewstate, which means that on postback there is less data in viewstate than the page is expecting. Try removing the controls in prerender which should happen after the saving of viewstate and this should solve your problem.

James :-)

Comment: You mean to say I should do this with Page_Init? I am not adding any new controls, rather removing.

Comment: What you need to do is make sure the ViewState and controls match - as long as you have the controls loaded and the viewstate in the loadviewstate stage matching, however you choose to do it, that should solve your problem.

Comment: Actually I am using a third-party library for the controls. Now clueless what really causes this problem. The behavior I observed is, anything more than two on certain section causes this. I know it's pretty abstract but still clueless how to debug this.